# MySQL dbForge - Querying between different connections (same schema)

Tags: mysql, schema, dbforge

I've just started using MySQL dbForge and I would like to know how to query between different connections (same schema used for all of them).

Here is my situation:

- **Connection:** DB1, **Schema:** My_schema, **Table:** APIKeys
- **Connection:** DB2, **Schema:** My_schema, **Table:** Coupons

Here I want to do a join between these two tables, but I'm not sure how to tell to dbForge that I'm working with different connections.

Happy New Year! Wish you all the best in 2019!

Looking forward to your replies. ;)

Comment: the dbs are on the same server of are on different servers ??

Comment: Yep. They are on the same server.

Comment: From our assessment, it seems that the problem is unrelated to the functionality of our product. Please consult the documentation provided below. It includes all the essential information and a step-by-step guide: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html
Note that it should work properly in connection with the replication. 

If the issue still persists and is related to our software, please fill out the form below. Provide us with a detailed description of the problem and the actions you have taken;
https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html

Answer (score 0):

In mysql once a connection is estblished  all the dbs  and the table accessible by the user are  (based on user grants ) directly usable as ..

```
 select a.col1, b.col1
 from db1.table1 a 
 inner join  db2.table2.col2 b  on a.keycol = b.colkey
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, that was not my question. My question was as title says "Querying between different connections...", not "Querying between different databases..."